# Panning screen on eeePc 701 with Ubuntu and Xfce

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, eee-pc, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to get panning work for my Asus eeePc 701. I installed Xubuntu 12.04 on it (runs great), but it won't move the visible area of the screen around when moving the mouse to the screen borders. Moving windows with the Alt key doesn't work either.

The xrandr command I used is

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --fb 800x600 --panning 800x600
```

Comment: For the panning, give this a try: xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 1x1

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but doesn't the desktop size need to be larger than the screen resolution for panning to make sense.  Did you want virtual desktops instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the X server released with 11.10 and apparently still present in 12.04.  Here is a description of the bug and some possible fixes which you might be able to try if you are a guru, but impenetrable for normal users.

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39949

Answer (score 1):

I think this doesn't work because of the `--fb` option. Try it without this.

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --panning 800x600
```

This works perfectly on my EeePC 701 running Xubuntu 10.10. If it doesn't work for you, please tell us, what happens after issueing the command.

Comment: I haven't my eeePC at hands, but I will try it out. I awarded you the 50 points bounty before they expire :)

Comment: Thanks a lot and I really hope this helps you, but I suspect that rbas answers might be the better one, because the bug he linked to seems to refer to your problem exactly (and I tried with 10.10 where the bug wasn't apparent).